# Looking for an rxjs operator like audit or throttle, but not quite

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I have a stream of emissions that need to be passed to a function `foo` (think of `foo` as of an observable emitting after some delay). The execution of `foo` takes quite some time, so when it's processing the first input, all subsequent emissions shall queue, i.e. wait for `foo` to finish. When `foo` has finished only the most recent emission in the queue shall be passed to `foo` as the next input, discarding all other emissions currently in the queue. So while `foo` is processing the second input, a new queue is building up, and so on.

[Audit](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/audit) does already come close. The problem is that, although emissions are queued while the `durationSelector` (our `foo`) is running, the source value that is picked when `foo` finishes (the most recent value in fact) will be directly emitted without passing again through the `durationSelector`.

You may think of `foo` as some kind of costly back-end calculation that can only be run one at a time and, once started, cannot be stopped. The source value emissions are simply http request that tell the server to recalculate `foo`. So while `foo` is already run, all incoming request will have to wait for `foo` to finish. If by that time 100 request have accumulated, of course I need to run `foo` again *only once*, but it needs to be run if there have been requests after the one already being processed.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a little customisation of exhaustmap, check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-exhaustmap-with-trailing

Comment: @maxime1992 Thanks. `exhaustMap` is indeed interesting, but if I understand correctly this does also swallow up source values while inner observable is not completed...

Comment: @maxime1992 I'm sorry you're right, that's exactly what I am looking for. Impressive!